# Publishing a bot in an organization teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

Tell me where you need to set these permissions to be able to use the created bot ?

[image]

Comment: Which role do you have on azure portal resource? If you don't have required role then need to check with your tenant admin.

Comment: Hi, Seems like custom app uploading is disabled by your admin. You can ask your admin to enable this option or upload and install the app in relevant scope.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Prithvi-MSFT in the comment section, Please check with your admin to enable  custom app uploading.

if you are  installing the app directly from the App Studio instead of that, download it, then Upload it by clicking "Upload a custom app" in Apps.
Check this for [Reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/you-don-t-have-permissions-to-add-for-adding-a-bot/m-p/918612)